# Site looks great in Firefox, Bad in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, navigation

I'm sure I'm not the first person to experience this, but here's the problem: my site looks great in Firefox, but horrible in Dreamweaver and Chrome. I had been editing the CSS live in Firefox to get it right, then I copied and pasted it into Dreamweaver and it's all screwy.

Here's the way it's supposed to look and does look in Firefox:

http://postimg.org/image/7gcm1tjxh/

And in Chrome/Dreamweaver:

http://postimg.org/image/ikq6ho2dp/

As you can see the top navigation bar is vertical, not horizontal. And the footer is bunched together in Chrome as well.

I went ahead and included all my code because I might have specified something in another element that is contradicting something else.

What is the solution to get the menu back to horizontal and the footer looking correct in every browser?

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}

html {
 background-color:#96d5cd;
}


#container {
 width:980px;
 border:1px solid #1f5c54;
 background-color:white;
 margin:2em auto;
}

hr {
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
display:block;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
clear:both;
}

#footer {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-family:amaranth, trebuchet, verdana, sans-serif;
margin-left:12px;
clear:both;
}

#footer li {
display:inline;
clear:both;
}

#footer ul{
margin-left:-37px;
margin-top:-30px;
}

#main {
position:relative;
background-color:#fec161;
height:700px;
margin-top:-10px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
}

#main #content {
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
height:400px;
text-align:justify;
}

#nav {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: patua-one;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
background-color:#fec161;
width:920px;
height:70px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-top:60px;
} 

#nav li{
display:inline;
}

#navigation {
margin-left:-30px;
padding-top:15px;
}

#social {
float:right;
}

#social li {
margin-right:10px;
margin-bottom:20px;
display:inline;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 margin-top: 0px;
 font-style: normal;
}

a:hover {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#1e777b;
}

#feature {
padding-left:10px;
overflow:hidden;
width:960px;
margin-top:-30px;
}


#footer {
 font-family:amaranth;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 margin-top:0px;
}

#header {
 font-family:patua-one;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 margin-top:0px;
 font-size:24px;
}

#header img {
 float:left;
margin-left:10px;
margin-top:10px;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: patua-one;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-transform: uppercase;
padding-top:10px;
}

#column1 {
float:left;
width:275px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:30px;
text-align:justify;
}

#column2 h2{
float:left;
width:275px;
margin-left:90px;
}

#column2 {
float:left;
width:275px;
margin-right:0px;
text-align:justify;
margin-left:20px;
}


#column3 {
float:right;
width:275px;
margin-right:10px;
text-align:justify;
}

#column3 h2 {
 float:left;
 width:275px;
 margin-left:220px;
}

h2 {
 font-weight: 400;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 line-height: 100%;
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One);
 font-family: patua-one;
 font-style: normal;
 font-size:24px;
}

#columns {
 margin-top:20px;
}

h3 {
font-family:amaranth;
}

div span.welcome {
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: patua-one;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>WELCOME :: Katie J Hunter :: Graphic Designer</title>

<link ref="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/images/favicon.ico" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One">
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/patua-one:n4:default;amaranth:n4:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

 <div id="header">
    <img src="images/KatieHunterLogo.png" alt="Katie Hunter Graphic Designer Logo" /><br />
    
    <br />
    
    <ul id="social">
     <p><li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Katie-Hunter-Graphic-Designer/1532575640337137" target="_blank"><img src="images/socialmedia_facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.twitter.com/kinetickatie" target="_blank"><img src="images/socialmedia_twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/katiejohunter" target="_blank"><img src="images/socialmedia_linkedin.png" alt="Linked In" /></a></li>
    </p></ul>
    
    <ul><p>
    <div id="navigation">
    <li><a href="index.html" target="_blank">Home</a> :: </li>
    <li><a href="about.html" target="_blank">About</a> ::</li> 
    <li><a href="services.html" target="_blank">Services</a> :: </li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">Portfolio</a> :: </li>
    <li><a href="blog.html" target="_blank">Blog</a> :: </li> 
    <li><a href="contact.html" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
    </div><!-- end navigation --></ul>
 </div><!-- end header -->
    
    <div id="feature">
    
     <img src="images/FeatureBanner.jpg" alt="banner" class="banner" /><br>
    
    </div><!-- end feature -->
    
    <div id="main">
     <div id="content">
        <h1><span class="welcome">Welcome!</span></h1>
        <hr style="height:1px; width:100%; border:1px solid black; background-color:black;" />
        
        <h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sapien velit, dictum vel semper id, vestibulum eu nisi. Phasellus ac ornare sapien. Praesent eget libero mollis ipsum eleifend lacinia non ut ligula. Sed quis sem at est laoreet aliquet. Donec ornare, ante ut fermentum ullamcorper, enim purus vehicula sem, non feugiat dolor nulla sed enim. Etiam odi o nibh, bibendum vel eros malesuada, elementum blandit quam. Integer aliquet finibus felis et eleifend.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sapien velit, dictum vel semper id, vestibulum eu nisi. Phasellus ac ornare sapien. Praesent eget libero mollis ipsum eleifend lacinia non ut ligula. Sed quis sem at est laoreet aliquet. Donec ornare, ante ut fermentum ullamcorper, enim purus vehicula sem, non feugiat dolor nulla sed enim. Etiam odio nibh, bibendum vel eros malesuada, elementum blandit quam. Integer aliquet finibus felis et eleifend.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sapien velit, dictum vel semper id, vestibulum eu nisi. Phasellus ac ornare sapien. Praesent eget libero mollis ipsum eleifend lacinia non ut ligula. Sed quis sem at est laoreet aliquet. Donec ornare, ante ut fermentum ullamcorper, enim purus vehicula sem, non feugiat dolor nulla sed enim. Etiam odio nibh, bibendum vel eros malesuada, elementum blandit quam. Integer aliquet finibus felis et eleifend.</h3>
     </div><!-- end content -->
          <div id="columns">
            <div id="column1">
    <h2>Services</h2>
    <hr style="height:1px; width:100%; border:1px solid black; background-color:black;" />
 <h3>Donec ornare, ante ut fermentum ullamcorper, enim purus vehicula sem, non feugiat dolor nulla sed enim.</h3>
    </div><!-- end column1 -->

    <div id="column2">
     <h2>Clients</h2>
     <hr style="height:1px; width:100%; border:1px solid black; background-color:black;" />
      <h3>Donec ornare, ante ut fermentum ullamcorper, enim purus vehicula sem, non feugiat dolor nulla sed enim.</h3>
    </div><!-- end column2 -->

    <div id="column3">
     <h2>Blog</h2>
     <hr style="height:1px; width:100%; border:1px solid black; background-color:black;" />
     <h3>Donec ornare, ante ut fermentum ullamcorper, enim purus vehicula sem, non feugiat dolor nulla sed enim.</h3>
    </div><!-- end column3 -->
     </div><!-- end columns -->
    </div><!-- end main -->
    
     <div id="footer">
        © copyright 2015 katie j hunter • all rights reserved</span>
        <ul>
      <li><a href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/index.html" target="_blank">Home</a></li> | 
      <li><a href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/about.html" target="_blank">About</a></li> | 
      <li><a href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/services.html" target="_blank">Services</a></li> | 
      <li><a href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/portfolio.html" target="_blank">Portfolio</a></li> | 
      <li><a href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/blog.html" target="_blank">Blog</a></li> |
      <li><a href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/contact.html" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
       </div><!-- end footer -->

</div><!-- end container -->



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to use **webkit** properties in css for different browser's support..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using bootstrap frame work. Its supports the latest mobile and browsers.

```
[http://www.bootply.com/4kihU2HqGf][1]


  [1]: http://getbootstrap.com/




    /* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css *//* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.logo {
  width: 210px;
  }
  .jumbotron {

    }
h1.name {
    color: #125952;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ffbc6b;
    margin-bottom: -19px;

  }

  .primary {
  background-color: #ffbc6b;
    border-radius: 1px;

    }
  .main-content {
  background-color: #ffbc6b;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #000;
        }


    .welcome {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
      color: #000;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
          }
       p {
    color: #000;
         font-weight: 400px;
        }

        .columns {
           color: #000;
           border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
           padding-bottom: 8px;
           margin-bottom: 8px;
            }
   section {
       background-color: #ffbc6b;
       padding: 10px;
    }
   .row {
      background-color: #ffbc6b;

    }

  .footer {
      background-color: #fff;

      margin: -12px 0px 0 -44px !important;

     }

.navbar-default {
    border: none;
  }

.copyright{
    margin-top: 10px;

  }
    <div class="container">
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <h1 class="name">Katie Hunter</h1>
      <h3 class="subtitle">Graphic Designer</h3>
    </div><!-- end logo -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default primary">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">HOME :: <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT ::</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES ::</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO ::</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BLOG ::</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT ::</a></li>

      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>


    <!-- end nav -->

  </header><!-- header -->

  <div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Your images goes here!</h1>

  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid main-content">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <h1 class="welcome">Welcome</h1>
    <p><strong>lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
      when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
      specimen book.
      It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic 
      typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with 
      the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more 
      recently with desktop publishing
      software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

      It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the 
      readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using 
      Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as 
      opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable 
      English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem
      Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will
      uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have 
      evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose 
      (injected humour and the like).</strong></p>
    </div><!-- end of col -->


        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h2 class="columns">SERVICES</h2>
          <p>lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
          Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
          when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
            specimen book.</p>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h2 class="columns">SERVICES</h2>
          <p>lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
          Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
          when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
            specimen book.</p>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h2 class="columns">SERVICES</h2>
          <p>lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
          Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
          when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
            specimen book.</p>

        </div>
</div><!-- end of container-fluid -->



      <div class="container copyright">
        <div class="col-sm-6 ">
          <p>© COPYRIGHT 2015 Katie J Hunter - ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</p>
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->




      <ul class="nav navbar-nav footer">
        <li><a href="#">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>

      </ul>



  </div><!-- /.container-fluid --></nav></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your css, you have specified `#nav li`, while the element you want to make inline is `#navigation li`

also you have given `footer ul` as `margin-top: -37px`, which is causing the ul to be bunched together with the copyright message.

P.S: i am not able to open the images as i am behind a proxy, but i'm guessing this is what you would want.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML isn't valid. You're using `<p>` and `<div>` tags as children of a lists element (ul).

Try replacing e.g. this:

```
<ul><p>
<div id="navigation">
<li><a href="index.html" target="_blank">Home</a> :: </li>
<li><a href="about.html" target="_blank">About</a> ::</li> 
<li><a href="services.html" target="_blank">Services</a> :: </li>
<li><a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">Portfolio</a> :: </li>
<li><a href="blog.html" target="_blank">Blog</a> :: </li> 
<li><a href="contact.html" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
</div><!-- end navigation --></ul>
```

With that:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" target="_blank">Home</a> :: </li>
        <li><a href="about.html" target="_blank">About</a> ::</li> 
        <li><a href="services.html" target="_blank">Services</a> :: </li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">Portfolio</a> :: </li>
        <li><a href="blog.html" target="_blank">Blog</a> :: </li> 
        <li><a href="contact.html" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- end navigation -->
```